# Displaying a D3 tree with multiple parents

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js, data-visualization

I currently have [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) graph implemented and I'm hoping to keep the structure and collapsibility while depicting a child node having multiple parents.  Is there a way to do this?  I looked into force graphs but I'm also wanting to preserve a set hierarchy (meaning a parent at level 1 can have a child and level 3 shown).  After a lot of research and tinkering with my current code, I am unable to figure my issues out.  Is there anyone who has any experience with displaying a D3 tree node with multiple parents?

Comment: Maybe "Sankey Diagrams" are more useful for you. Each child can has multiple parents.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering what I did to answer my question.  I ended up making a force diagram behave in the same manner as a tree.  This provided me the possibility of having multiple parents and I just had to do some fiddling with how the diagram used forces in order to preserve hierarchy.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your modified force diagram?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a copy of it.  It was for a project that I do not have access to anymore but I can show you the two examples that I used to create it.  The force-directed graph came from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 and the tree part was modeled after this https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083.  We combined the two and messed with gravity on the force directed graph.  We also had to anchor the top parent of the force directed graph on the left.  Hope this helps a bit and sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @Ally can you provide a screenshot at least? very curious. thanks

Comment: This sounds like the holy grail! Shame it was lost