# How to build a tree with nodes having multiple parents?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using the [cluster layout](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) of D3.js and I'd like to allow multiple parents.

How can a node have multiple parents ?

Here is what I have so far: ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL817x5a/))

```js
var json = {
  "name": "cluster",
  "children": [{
    "name": "AgglomerativeCluster"
  }, {
    "name": "CommunityStructure"
  }, {
    "name": "HierarchicalCluster"
  }, {
    "name": "MergeEdge"
  }]
};

var width = 500,
  height = 250;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
  .size([width, height - 160]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 40)");

var nodes = cluster.nodes(json);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(cluster.links(nodes))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d, i) {
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "V" + (d.target.y / 2) + "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
  });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);

node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 3)
  .attr("dy", function(d) {
    return d.children ? -10 : 10;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.children ? "end" : "start";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'm wondering if it is possible. The data model currently doesn't allow this kind of behavior IMHO, but I don't know a lot of D3, so maybe there is a way around ?

Comment: For info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554450/a-tree-where-each-node-could-have-multiple-parents

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/6afc2ecb05b191359862

Comment: And according to the comments here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727855/displaying-a-d3-tree-with-multiple-parents you can't do this in d3 you can however use cola.js : http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/

Comment: @thatOneGuy It seems a bit messy since it doesn't adapt the order of the children. Using links with angle would make it unreadable.

Comment: Perhaps you could manipulate the data so it's just nodes and links, but on manipulation, give each tier an index, i.e the level it is at in the tree. Then pass this data (as nodes and links) to D3's force layout and then set the positions of each node according on the index you gave previously. And spread the nodes out which ever way you want to lay them out. Just an idea :) Shouldn't be too difficult